# Pytest Run a Start-up Script

Tags: pytest

Before pytest actually collects and executes my module , I need to run an external start-script from another module to do some patching, i would like to edit the pytest source. Where exactly in pytest source code should I edit to achieve this? I mean my start-up script must run by default before all other activities.
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Add `conftest.py` to your project home folder and your startup lay in `pytest_sessionstart()`

```
def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    pass
```

ref. [hook starting](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart)

Answer (score 0):

You can call pytest from a startup script - see [pytest Documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html#calling-pytest-from-python-code)

```
import pytest

# to your setup stuff
pytest.main()
```

If you don't want to use a startup script you could achieve it by writing a pytest plugin - see [pytest Plugin Documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/writing_plugins.html)

Comment: This is a nice option, which i currently have in my code base.. I am actually looking into editing pytest source code to call some magic functions from other module/package, so that before pytest could do collection and execution, objects would be in memory for my tasks

Answer (score 0):

Can be done @ _pytest/main.py , Refer function -- pytest_runtestloop